# Blue Prism unable to identify object" no elements match the supplied query terms"

Tags: blueprism

I am very new to the RPA and trying to automate a simple process using blue prism(opening a web based application -->clicking on an link and filling the form).
While running the object studio step by step i am able to navigate till end but while running the flow from process studio, after the website is getting opened i am getting error "no elements match the supplied query items"

Comment: Have you included enough wait time? Have you spied the element and configured the match attributes to disregard or properly handle dynamic identifiers? Can you post a bit of your code?

Comment: Assuming you are properly using waits, elements on a webpage often change at runtime, i.e. parameters of the element are generated when the page is loaded. This means that it might not have exactly the same parameters when you load the page a 2nd time, or a 3rd time, when compared to the 1st time the same page loads.

Answer (score 0):

A process in BluePrism can have different speed of execution depending on the way you're running it.

If you're running application using "Step" function (hotkey F5), then BluePrism waits a long time between executing actions. A "Step above" (hotkey F10) is much faster, but the fastest possible speed of execution is from control room.

The delay from "Step", or "Step above" can be enough to make process work during the development. Once the process is moved to control room, then the delay is gone and sometimes the process might be running too fast. It can happen, that the BluePrism is trying to interact with the element that does not yet exist.

To make process work in control room, you need to have additional wait stages that will ensure that the process is not running ahead of the applications that are being automated. Whenever you're interacting with any element then you need to be sure that it exists.